# Java lottery Machine Task

Tags: java

My task is to allow a user to input their lottery numbers and check if
they have won the jackpot.
The user should be given the chance to enter 4 numbers. Each number should be in the range 1-99. If
the user enters a number that is less than 1, or greater than 99, then the programme should prompt
them to enter a number in the correct range. You should use a while loop to ensure that the user inputs
the correct number. What should the exit condition of the while loop be?

I have tried making a while loop as the task asks me to do. this did not work. I am completely and utterly stuck.

```
String password = "MyNameJeff";
Scanner dave = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("lottery numbers");
int UserInput = dave.nextLine();

while (!password.equals(UserInput)) {
    System.out.println random math command <----
    UserInput = dave.nextLine();
}

System.out.println("Lottery numbers here?");
```

Comment: What is the purpose of password MyNameJeff ?

Answer (score 1):

This `while` loop will take the first userInput and check its range between 1 and 99 inclusive.

```
while(userInput < 1 || userInput > 99){
    System.out.println("Please re-enter another lottery number: ");
    userInput=dave.nextInt();
}
```

If it is not in the range 1 to 99, it will request the user to re-enter another lottery number.

Answer (score 0):

the condition is when you want to stop the `while` loop. for example

you may want to stop when you have 4 numbers

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> choices = new ArrayList<>();

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        boolean done = false;
        //we set done to false, and the condition is "while !(not) done"
        while (!done) {
            try {
                System.out.println("write lottery numbers:");
                String userInput = scanner.nextLine();
                Integer result = Integer.parseInt(userInput);
                // compareTo is a bit tricky, read the javadoc for information
                if (result.compareTo(0) < 0) {
                    System.out.println("dont add number less then 0");
                    continue;
                    }
                if (result.compareTo(99) > 0) {
                    System.out.println("dont add number more then 99");
                    continue;
                }
                //adding more result is the only way done will be eventually true
                choices.add(result);
                //set to done when the size of the list is 4
                done = choices.size() == 4;
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println("Only add number");
            }

    }

    System.out.println("Lottery numbers here?");
    choices.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Check this code

```
public static void main (String[]args) throws IOException, ParseException {
        int [] winNumbers = new int[4];
        int [] numbers = new int[4];
        int indx=0;
        System.out.println("Enter Lottery Numbers");
        while (indx<4) {
            System.out.println("Enter number: ");
            Scanner dave = new Scanner(System.in);
            try {
                String in = dave.nextLine().trim();
                int inNum = Integer.parseInt(in);
                if (inNum>0 && inNum<100) {
                    numbers[indx] = inNum;
                    indx++;
                    continue;
                }
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException | NullPointerException nfe) {
            }
            System.out.println("Please enter a number in the range 1-99");
        }
        Random rand = new Random();
        for (int i=0; i<winNumbers.length; i++){

            int r = rand.nextInt(98);//will get a random number between 0-98
            r +=1; // for the number to be on the space 1-99
            winNumbers[i]=r;
        }
        System.out.println("User entered: " + Arrays.toString(numbers));
        System.out.println("Lottery numbers here: " + Arrays.toString(winNumbers));
    }
```

Two int arrays are used with size 4.
One is filled using Scanner. There are some checks:
trim(): will remove any whitespace that the user might enter
catch:  will catch a numberFormatException or null. It will print nothing.

If the code does not enter the if(inNum>0 && inNum<100) then the indx counter will not increment and the code will print the error message: Please enter a number...

The second part of the code generates 4 random numbers and stores them in the second array.

Finally, it prints the two arrays.